# my C code in visual studio is showing debug error

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

This is C programming code that I have written. When I run this code it shows debug error the visual code is showing this warning as well.

`Warning 6385   Reading invalid data from 'my_newarray':  the readable size is '4' bytes, but '8' bytes may be read.`

My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;   
    printf("enter the size of an array: ");

    scanf_s("%i", &n);

    int my_array[] = { calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int)) };  
    int my_newarray[] = { calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int)) };

    printf("enter only 0s and 1s n times:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%i", &my_array);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (my_array[j] > my_array[j + 1])
        {
            my_array[j] = my_newarray[j + 1];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < (n+1); k++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", my_newarray[k]);
    }

    free(my_array);
    free(my_newarray);
}
```

Comment: Ouch! Syntax, syntax, syntax... `int *my_array = calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int));`, you cannot assign an address to an *Array*, you must use a *Pointer*, there are no `{...}` (brace initializer syntax) needed.  (same for `my_newarray`)

Comment: Also always ***Validate*** every input, e.g. `if (scanf_s("%i", &n) != 1) { /* handle error */ return 1; }`

Comment: You need a C book https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

These declarations

```
int my_array[] = { calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int)) };  
int my_newarray[] = { calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int)) };
```

are incorrect. In fact you are trying to create arrays with the element type `int` that have single elements that are initialized by a value of the type `void *` that is returned by calls of calloc.

You need to declare pointers like

```
int *my_array = calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int));  
int *my_newarray = calloc((n + 1), sizeof(int));
```

Also this call

```
scanf_s("%i", &my_array);
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean either

```
scanf_s("%i", &my_array[i]);
```

or

```
scanf_s("%i", my_array + i);
```

That is you need to fill elements of the allocated array except the last element that was already zero initialized by using a call of `calloc`.

Also this assignment

```
my_array[j] = my_newarray[j + 1];
```

and the following loop

```
for (int k = 0; k < (n+1); k++)
{
    printf("%i\n", my_newarray[k]);
}
```

do not make a great sense because all elements of the array `my_newarray` were zero-initialized by a call of calloc. So you could just write

```
my_array[j] = 0;
```

Comment: You are quick tonight my friend!